# Unpack from hex to double in Python

Tags: python, double, hex

Python: Unpack from hex to double

This is the value

```
value = ['\x7f', '\x15', '\xb7', '\xdb', '5', '\x03', '\xc0', '@']
```

I tried

```
unpack('d', value)
```

but he needs a string for unpacking. It is a list now. But when I change it to a string, the length will change from 8 to 58. But a double needs a value of the length 8.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`''.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) join to convert the list to a string:

```
>>> value = ['\x7f', '\x15', '\xb7', '\xdb', '5', '\x03', '\xc0', '@']
>>> ''.join(value)
'\x7f\x15\xb7\xdb5\x03\xc0@'
>>> from struct import unpack
>>> unpack('d', ''.join(value))
(8198.4207676749193,)
```

Answer (score 7):

Note that there are two ways to convert this to a double, depending on whether the cpu is bigendian oe littleendian, so it's best to be explicit about which one you want

```
>>> from struct import unpack
>>> value = ['\x7f', '\x15', '\xb7', '\xdb', '5', '\x03', '\xc0', '@']
>>> unpack('<d', ''.join(value))[0]
8198.42076767492
>>> unpack('>d', ''.join(value))[0]
1.4893584640656973e+304
```

and just for fun - here's how to decode the double explicitly

```
>>> value = ['\x7f', '\x15', '\xb7', '\xdb', '5', '\x03', '\xc0', '@']
>>> bytes = map(ord,reversed(value))
>>> sign = (1,-1)[bytes[0]>>7]
>>> exp = ((0x7f&bytes[0])<<4) + (bytes[1]>>4) - 1023
>>> mantissa = reduce(lambda x,y: (x<<8) + y, bytes[2:], bytes[1]&0xf)
>>> sign*2**exp*(1+mantissa*2**-52)
8198.4207676749193
```

Answer (score 1):

Note verify the value before implementation use below functions to convert HEX->Double or Double->HEX.

```
>>> import struct
>>> def double_to_hex(f):
    return hex(struct.unpack('<Q', struct.pack('<d', f))[0])

>>> def hex_to_double(f):
    return struct.unpack('!d', bytes.fromhex(f))[0]

>>> data = 12.982947
>>> hex_value = double_to_hex(data)
>>> print(hex_value)
0x4029f744d4456712
>>> double_value = hex_to_double(hex_value[2:])
>>> print(double_value)
12.982947
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `ctypes` library for this conversion.

```
from ctypes import pointer, cast, POINTER, c_double, c_longlong

def convert_longlong_to_double(s):
    try:
        i = int(s, 10)                   # convert from hex to a Python int
    except Exception:
        i = s
    cp = pointer(c_longlong(i))           # make this into a c long long
    fp = cast(cp, POINTER(c_double))  # cast the long long pointer to a double pointer
    return fp.contents.value         # dereference the pointer, get the double
```

Example usage:

```
r1 = 0
r2 = 0
r3 = 16473
r4 = 0

longlong = (r1 << 16) | (r2 << 0) | (r3 << 48) | (r4 << 32)
print(convert_longlong_to_double(longlong))
```